# El elemento de verificación CheckedComboboxEdit no funciona correctamente

Tags: c#, devexpress

Buen día,

Estoy usando DevExpress para programar y tengo un problema.

Al recuperar los datos de un datagridview hacia el combobox, este muestra la información correcta, más no se tilda o chequea.

Este problema no ocurre, si comento la linea del ValueMember, ahí funciona correctamente, pero no es lo que quiero, ya que necesito recuperar el IdProvincia de esa selección en otro campo de texto.

cls_general myCls_general = new cls_general();

```
        myCls_general.conexion_mssql("1");

        strSQL = " SELECT IdProvincia,Provincia   " +
                 "   FROM Provincias " +
                 " ORDER BY Provincia ASC";

        myCboContacProvinciaDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myCls_general.myConnection);
        myCboContacProvinciaDataSet = new DataSet();
        myCboContacProvinciaDataAdapter.Fill(myCboContacProvinciaDataSet, "Provincias");


        cbo_list_provincias.Properties.DataSource = myCboContacProvinciaDataSet.Tables["Provincias"];
        cbo_list_provincias.Properties.DisplayMember = "Provincia";
        cbo_list_provincias.Properties.ValueMember = "IdProvincia";

        myCboContacProvinciaDataAdapter.Dispose();
        myCboContacProvinciaDataSet.Dispose();

        myCls_general.cerrar_conexion();
```

Comment: Anexo una pregunta en este foro similar a la mía, pero que no entiendo la solución.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249430/checkedcomboboxedit-check-item-does-not-work-properly

Comment: Porque en la pregunta no esta la solucion, solo es una pregunta.

Comment: No termino de entender tu pregunta. Porque decis " este muestra la información correcta, más no se tilda o chequea." y luego "Este problema no ocurre, si comento la linea del ValueMember,"

Comment: Si elimino el ValueMember y recupero los datos del grid, al desplegar el combobox, se muestra tildado la opción que está seleccionada. Si dejo el ValueMember, por alguna extraña razón, me recupera el valor del combobox, más este al desplegar el combobox, no está tildado o checkeado.